# Fix Linux grub with boot-repair with an old BIOS PC and a GPT drive?

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-loader, gpt, mbr

I have a GPT formatted SSD Drive that I have moved from a rather new laptop to an older one that has an old BIOS. The Linux systems installed on it work fine (Kubuntu 22.04 and Mint 21), although [I cannot install Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1810527/1039759) (but that's another matter that doesn't concern us here).

I want to fix the grub so that it boots into Kubuntu (set Kubuntu as the grub location). —After trying to install Windows and failing, and then trying to fix the grub with grub-repair and failing, as explained here, I have installed a supplementary Linux Mint system in order to be able to access the old one. Now I want to get rid of the second Linux, but that would make my laptop unusable unless I make Kubuntu the the default boot before or after removing Mint (which I don't know how).—

With MBR drives it seemed very simple to me to use Boot Repair and fix frequent errors after installing or removing operating systems. But since a few years, with UEFI and GPT I usually end up with solutions that don't involve Boot Repair.

Here, I don't want to re-format the drive and change to a MBR structure.

On the other hand, changing or updating to UEFI is not an option on this machine.

I get this error saying the session is in BIOS / legacy mode.

[image]

[image]

Is Boot Repair only handling GPT under UEFI?

---

- By the way: after taking the drive out and connecting it externally to a UEFI computer, can I use Boot Repair on that computer to set grub location on the Kubuntu 22.04 partition (on that GPT external drive) so that back on the old PC it boots as intended? — Or is thus setting grub location on a partition of an external drive going to destroy the grub configuration of the UEFI computer?

Comment: So you're saying you have a laptop which can not from gpt, because it only knows how to boot from an MBR? Then you simply can't boot from a GPT partitioned drive, and there's nothing that any program (never heard of Boot Repair before) can do about it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - `you have a laptop which can not from gpt`- No, the laptop boots fine from  a GPT drive: it boots Linux. - `it only knows how to boot from an MBR`: no, installed Linux can boot, the problem is with the Boot Repair tool on live USB, it complains the laptop is in legacy. (I cannot install windows on that but I can Linux: https://superuser.com/a/1810527/1039759)

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: That it boots Linux didn't say it boots from GPT.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Linux can indeed work in BIOS mode in a GPT drive unlike Windows (cf. my answer below). Perhaps it shouldn't? But it actually does.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - you seem to confuse GPT and UEFI: Linux can boot from a GPT drive (GPT is a drive characteristic) even if the computer has a UEFI configuration (UEFI here means non_BIOS, a computer configuration).

Comment: Exactly, @ChanganAuto.. So the fact that Linux boots doesn't imply that the BIOS supports loading the bootloader from ESP on a GPT partitioned disk.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Please don't down vote a legitimate question. Could you instruct me how to improve it? ` doesn't imply that the BIOS supports loading the bootloader from ESP on a GPT partitioned disk` - have I implied that? This is strictly about how to fix grub with Boot Repair. Maybe I was not clear I'll re-edit.

Comment: @cipricus GPT is not a disk characteristic, it's how the disk is partitioned. You can partition any character of disk in and way you like - whether your computer can later on so something with that is a separate question . Actually, that's the question you're conflating here: you say "Linux boots, that's proof that my computer knows how to boot from a GPT formatted drive". But as the answer that ChanganAuto gave you to your previous question, that isn't true - Linux can be loaded in many ways.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - You are trying to lecture me instead of providing an answer to a question that you do understand, don't you? But you keep using confusing terminology: like `GPT is not a disk characteristic, it's how the disk is partitioned`. - It's like saying "the sphere is not a balloon's characteristic, its just the form the balloon takes".

Comment: Related: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR BIOS can boot GPT.

Comment: It should be said that if you intend to have a dual-boot then the strict requirements of Windows take precedence. Meaning: You must have the drive partitioned as 'msdos' (MBR) for any old BIOS based machine.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - `if you intend to have a dual-boot then the strict requirements of Windows take precedence` - well, that aspect is settled: I give up Windows on that machine as long as the drive GPT configuration must be kept. In the future I'll move the drive to a UEFI-capable machine, and an old MBR+Win10 drive on the old-BIOS one. It's just for the moment that I have to keep this odd marriage..

Comment: Also on that page: [Tricking old BIOS into booting from GPT](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Tricking_old_BIOS_into_booting_from_GPT) - maybe check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/500431/1210606

Most Linux based OSes can indeed work in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode with a GPT drive provided it has a small `bios_grub` partition - ~2 MiB, unformatted, i.e., no file system - acting as a "fake MBR" (GPT has no Master Boot Record).

Then [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can be used for installing GRUB again for your Kubuntu. Alternatively you can boot from a Ubuntu/Kubuntu live/installation media and select the option to boot from the internal drive; then simply (re-)install GRUB for BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode:

```
sudo  apt-get  install  grub-pc-bin
sudo  grub-install /dev/sdX
```

where `sdX` is the target drive.

Comment: I know that `bios_grub` partition is needed, I have created it in order to install my Linuxes. `Then Boot Repair can be used for installing GRUB again for your Kubuntu`: that is what I cannot do! Boot Repair live session asks for EFI. `select the option to boot from the internal drive`: I have booted from a live session, but cannot use boot-repair, as indicated. Or should install GRUB for BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode before using boot-repair?

Comment: That message is confusing and likely doesn't mean exactly what it says. Boot Repair has been in use for many years now and it always supported BIOS mode.

Comment: It seems to expect a EFI configuration because the drive is GPT. It explicitely asks to change from legacy to UEFI, although no UEFI is available.

Comment: And there's no way to cancel/override the message and proceed? TBH, I never used Boot Repair in such scenario (or at all, most of the times) but also never heard of problems with it. You certainly aren't the first to try it in a BIOS installation in GPT and if there were problems questions would have popped up here, at AskUbuntu or SuperUser, me thinks.

Comment: Fixed it in the end with boot-repair and posted answer. Thank you!

Comment: How you boot install or repair media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs or repairs. So if you want BIOS, you must boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode. If booted or from a CHroot, you can install grub-pc for BIOS or grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end:

- Accept option to update the tool
- Select advanced options
- Select "Grub location" tab
- Select the new OS to boot by default
- *Un-check* options for separate `boot/...` partitions
- Select `sda` for GRUB location

[image]